# error in generating file with system date in java

Tags: java

I am having trouble generating file with the system date as part of the filename.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
 private static void writeFile(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myList,SourceBundle source) 
 {
    StringBuffer sbRequestControl;
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YYYY");
    Date now = new Date(0);
    File f = new File("MyFile_" + format.format(now) + ".csv");
 }
```

And below is the output I'm getting: **MyFile_365-12-1970.csv**

Comment: Why are you using `new Date(0)`?  This will set the `Date` to the Unix Epoch (1970), not todays date.  You could also use `format.format(System.currentTimeMillis())` and save yourself the creation of a short lived object

Comment: your date pattern should be dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: The constructor 'Date();' is undefined that's why it is prompting to put value inside.

Comment: make sure use the right import `import java.util.Date` as it is certainly not undefined `Date now = new Date()`

Comment: This resolved the issue, the previous import is using the sql. Thanks!

Comment: I have update my answer please accept this answer if I helped you resolve this issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong date pattern. You do n't need a separate String like I am using but I perfer it this way.

```
DateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String datepart = dateFormat.format(now);
File f = new File("MyFile_" + datepart + ".csv");
```

---

And yes as per comments you will get `01-01-1970` because you are using `new Date(0)`. If you want todays date just use `new Date()` that will results in `31-07-2015`

---

**Update**
Date import should be `import java.util.Date`